# Perform a calculation based on other criteria

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, calculated-column-formula, syntax, support

sorry in advance supernoob here failing hard and need help. I'm trying to create a timesheet in sharepoint that will eventually be a powerapp then go into PowerBI and I'm struggling bad with the sharepoint bit. So far I've got a column for the number of days between two dates( I've added +1 to count the current day). I've also got a column for users to select full or half days called H/F days.

What I want to do now is create a column called work hours - this should multiply the days by 7.4 if the H/F days column reads "full" and 3.7 if the HF days column reads "half".

In excel I would do it with sum IF and I could do it with PowerBI further on down the line, but I want the ux to be as streamlined as possible in PowerApps

So far I've tried =IF[h/fdays]=half,SUM[days]*3.7,IF[h/fdays]=full,SUM[days]*7.4

but I just get sharepoint fail screen , halp pls

Comment: try browsing Questions using the Calculated Column Formula tag:  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculated-column-formula

Answer (score 0):

I was able to recreate your issue, which appears to be cause by using an IF function in the Create Column formula field. The steps I used to resolve the issue are as follows:

1. Create a Calculated field which references another field. This allows us to bypass the error appearing on creation of the column.
2. In the List Settings, edit your new column to `=IF([field]="half","T","F")`
3. Refresh your form and see if this if properly returning "T" or "F". *If this is not working, refer to my Note below*
4. Edit the column to `=IF([field]="half",3.7*[Days field],7.4*[Days field])`

   - Refer directly to your column where you are storing the number of days instead of using a SUM function.

**Note:** There may be an issue with using "/" in your field name. If the above steps don't resolve your issue, try changing the field name to not include symbols.