# Calculate "Due Date" in business days based on Priority Level

Tags: calculated-column

I have been around the world wide web and back, tons of sites and examples and cannot find a solution. I can either find one piece of the puzzle or the other but not all of it. I have tried multiple formulas but everything throws a syntax error. I'm not sure if you can nest IF(AND statements but that's what I have been trying to do for each scenario.

I need to calculate the "Due Date" (in business days) based on Priority.

- Critical - 24 business hours (1 business day)
- Rush - 48 business hours (2 business days)
- Standard - 5 business days

I figure it out, probably the long way, but it works! I created a nested statement for each separate WEEKDAY scenario/priority level.

=IF(AND(Priority="Critical",WEEKDAY(Created)>5),Created+3,
IF(AND(Priority="Critical",WEEKDAY(Created)>1),Created+1,
IF(AND(Priority="Critical",WEEKDAY(Created)=1),Created+2,
IF(AND(Priority="Rush",WEEKDAY(Created)>4),Created+4,
IF(AND(Priority="Rush",WEEKDAY(Created)>1),Created+2,
IF(AND(Priority="Rush",WEEKDAY(Created)=1),Created+3,
IF(AND(Priority="Standard",WEEKDAY(Created)>6),Created+9,
IF(AND(Priority="Standard",WEEKDAY(Created)>1),Created+7,
Created+8))))))))

Answer (score 1):

I ran into an issue yesterday with creating calculated columns which include a IF formula. (For full details, see my answer here: [Perform a calculation based on other criteria](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/234956/perform-a-calculation-based-on-other-criteria/234959#234959))

You should be able to nest Formulas with no problem once the field is created, but SharePoint seems to have an issue with creating calculated columns with IF formulas. The work around to this is to create the field with a dummy value initially, then edit the calculation to include your IF formula afterwards.